my keyframes wont animate
On Blender 4.2, I'm trying to animate my country ball. But when I press I in the timeline, all what appears is all channels, only selected channels, and in active groups. When I click on one of them, nothing happens. When I click outside the timeline it does insert a keyframe but when I go to factors and change the tapper to 2 or 3, it doesn't animate the country ball. Here's what it looks like:


You have to press I over the field you want to animate to add a keyframe directly to that. If you press I in the Dopesheet/Timeline then it won't know where to add it, other than all the channels you have in the timeline or the active one you have selected.

By default, the only properties that you will keyframes by hovering animation editors or the viewport are the selected objects' transforms and their custom properties if they have any. It will not add keyframes to other data blocks, even if they are related to a selected object.
Here you are trying to animate a property of a modifier. To set a keyframe on that property, you need to hover it with your mouse while pressing I. Or  RMB > Insert Keyframe, or click the dot near the property to add a keyframe (it will then become a diamond to show its has keyframes).


Omg thank you so much!! :)

You're welcome, don't forget to hit the ✔️ in the top-left corner of my answer to accept it ;)
